# How do I add timer in my bot like the other giveaway bots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

What I want is a timer in my bot giveaway embed message which like works when the bot is off and the timer still updates itself without showing that the message was edited.

So I am just showing what I have done in embed:

```
   const embed = new MessageEmbed();
   embed.setAuthor({
        name: `${message.guild.name} GiveAways!`,
        iconURL: `${message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`
   });
   embed.setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`);
   embed.setTitle(`${title.toUpperCase()}`);
   embed.setColor("BLURPLE");
   embed.setDescription(
      `
      **React With  To Enter!**
      **Ends In: ${time} ${}!**
      **Hosted By: ${message.author}!**
      `
   );
   embed.setFooter({
       text: `${winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1)} Winners | Ends`
   });
   embed.setTimestamp(Date.now() + ms(duration));

   const sentGiveaway = await channel.send({
      content: "||@everyone|| **   GIVEAWAY   **",
      embeds: [embed]
   });
   sentGiveaway.react("");
```

`title` - This provide the title for the giveaway.
`time` - This coverts the duration entered by user to the full name. E.g: 4d => 4 Days.
`winnerCount` - This provide how many winners will win the giveaway.
`duration` - This takes the argument from user.
`Date.now + ms(duration)` - This provide the exact time when the giveaway will end.

What is my embed doing - this is my giveaway embed where I am providing the the duration and stuff, The `embed.setTimestamp()` does not do what I want, it jus tells when will the giveaway end. (I am not providing full code cause some people told me to not to paste full code)

What I want - I want that in the description next to the variable time, I want a automatic time update which people can send and the bots can send but I don't know how to do that, I have seen many bots send the timer in there messages.

[This the thing I am talking about, check the highlighted thing you will see that this thing update itself when the bot is switched off. (Click the link to see the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ycQn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [unix timestamps](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting).

They use **seconds** instead of milliseconds, so you will need to do the necessary division when working with milliseconds (divide by 1000 & Math.floor() it)

For example:

```js
const timestamp = new Date().getTime() + 600000 // (in 10 minutes)
const timestampInSecs = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000); // Necessary division

// Choose appropriate formatting option - the one GiveawayBot uses is R
const timestampString = `<t:${timestampInSecs}:R>`;
```